# Adding new operations to an existing WSDL. Is it required to recompile existing client?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a web service and one client application that's using it.

Now I want to add a new operation in this WSDL for a new client. **There is no impact on the existing operations of the WSDL. Only a new operation is being added.**

Is it required to recompile the existing client after this change?

Answer (score 2):

If you only added a new operation and changed nothing else then the existing client won't be afected. There is no need to recompile the client.

Here are some more details: [What are considered non-breaking or backwards-compatible changes to a WSDL contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786935/what-are-considered-non-breaking-or-backwards-compatible-changes-to-a-wsdl-contr)

Answer (score -1):

No,just delete the old wsdl file from /WEB-INF/wsdl folder and again expose your updated class as a web service,that will create the new wsdl.