# How do you add versioning information to web services?

Tags: weblogic, versioning, soa, osb

I would be interested to get the community’s opinions on the best way to add versioning information to web services.

In our company we work with Weblogic WLS, OSB and SOA. Now we want to attach the versioning information to the web services, so we see/recognize per web service the current version. The best way would be to work with metadata.

My Question:

What is best practice in this case?

Has someone experience with it?

Knows someone a good tutorial?

Comment: In case of REST we add that as a part of URI , but if you are using SOAP , I suggest you add that as part of response headers

Comment: In our application we do it by appending the version information in wsdl namespace.  http://www.xxx.com/intf/context/module/submodule/Service/ver (e.g. http://www.xxx.com/intf/ecom/seller/order/CreateOrder/v1)

Comment: @VKSingla and how explicit would that be if you set the version in the headers? No, it has to be clear enough. Have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314685/versioning-soap-body-vs-entire-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach I've found for SOAP services is [Web Service Contract Design and Versioning for SOA](http://servicetechbooks.com/wsc)

For REST services, you want to [version your media-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972226/how-to-version-rest-uris/975394#975394)